# mongoose 'findById' returns null with valid id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

**EDIT [SOLVED]:**

I was connecting to the wrong database...

I changed

`var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/wifiplz'`

to

`var dbURI = 'mongodb://localhost/wifiPlz'`

so all of this was due to a typo (uncapitalized p). Anyone with this type of problem make sure you are connecting to the right database!

---

Here is my schema file (`location.js`):

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var openingTimeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  days: {type: String, required: true},
  opening: String,
  closing: String,
  closed: {type: Boolean, required: true}
});

var reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  author: String,
  rating: {type: Number, min: 0, max: 5, required: true},
  createdOn: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
  reviewText: String
});

var locationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {type: String, required: true},
  address: {type: String, required: true},
  rating: {type: Number, default: 0, min: 0, max: 5},
  facilities: [String],
  coords: {type: [Number], index: '2dsphere'},
  openingTimes: [openingTimeSchema],
  reviews: [reviewSchema]
});

// compiling schema as 'Location' model
mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema);
```

In my routes, I map the route to appropriate controller:

```
router.get('/locations/:locationId', locationsCtrl.locationRead);
```

In my controller (`locationsCtrl.js`) I try to find a location by id:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Location = mongoose.model('Location');

module.exports.locationRead = function(req, res) {
  Location
    .findById(req.params.locationId)
    .exec(function(err, location) {
      if (err) throw err;

      res.status(200);
      res.json(location); // returns null
    });
}
```

When I tested this, I am always getting `null` for valid ids. Would appreciate some insight as to why. Thanks.

edit:

Checking for the name of the collection on my computer using `mongo` and `show collections`, I get `locations` as the collection name. This is as expected. Although specifying `mongoose.model('Location', locationSchema, 'locations')` doesn't have any effect.

Comment: What is your mongoose version? or add `mongoose.set('debug', true);` to check more information from log.

Comment: Here is one similar issue list, https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3079, it may help you.

Comment: Ten dollars says this is an existing collection in your database that is actually called `"location"` rather than the plural `"locations"` that mongoose is expecting. The referenced collection is the "plural" of the model name by default. You can change this by doing `mongoose.model("Location",locationSchema,"location")` to specify the collection name as the third argument. If it's not the collection, then you are likely connecting to the wrong database. Failing all that, `console.log(req.params.locationId)` to make sure that you are actually picking up what you think. These are common errors.

Comment: The collection name is `locations` on my computer. I've also used `mongoose.model(''Location', locationSchema, 'locations')`, that didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Make following changes :

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Location = mongoose.model('Location');

module.exports.locationRead = function(req, res) {
  Location
    .findOne({_id: req.params.locationId}, function (err, location){
      if (err) throw err;
      res.status(200);
      res.json(location); // returns null
    });
}
```

`_id` could be your any field so replace your db field with _id but make sure that field should be primary in nature or unique. If it's not create an index over that field.