# How can I grab the correct object from the database via the id given on mongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mern

I have a link like so:

```
const SpotIndexItem = ({ spot }) => (
  <Link to={`/spots/${spot._id}`}>
    <li>
      <p>Put image here</p>
      <p>{spot.name}</p>
    </li>
  </Link>
);
```

And it leads to the detail page of the index item. In the container component of the detail page, I have this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => ({
  spot: state.entities.spots[ownProps.match.params.spotId] 
});
```

And I'm rendering the item detail component like so in my `app.js` file:

```
<Route exact path="/spots/:spotId" component={SpotDetail} />
```

And this is in my route/api/spots.js file:

```
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
  Spot.findById(req.params.id)
    .then(spot => res.json(spot))
    .catch(err =>
      res.status(404).json({ nospotfound: 'No spot found with that ID' })
    );
});
```

But I keep getting this error message:

The output errors:

[image]

Is there a way of doing this with the `spot._id`? Are there any built in `find` methods that I could use here to get the object with a specific `_id`?

**UPDATE:**

- Out of curiosity, I also tried these routes in Postman and the index
  route works perfectly fine. However, when I try to do a route like
  this: `localhost:5000/api/spots/5e4317871c9d440000b1613f`, I get
  `null` instead of the object.
- I also found this post:
  [mongoose 'findById' returns null with valid id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906859/mongoose-findbyid-returns-null-with-valid-id),
  which solved the problem via connecting to the right database. I'm
  new to mongoDB, but I'm fairly sure that I've set up my database
  correctly. My app is connected to the `test` database (I don't have the ability on here to add images yet, but
  here's a link to what my database looks like):

  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVv7P.png)

Comment: You're use `mongoose` right?

Comment: Yes! Using mongoose @TitusSutioFanpula

Comment: Then this `Spot.findById (req.params.id)` should work to find object by id

Comment: Ahh, ok. That makes sense. I'm guessing that I'll need to do that in my `mapStateToProps` to get the right `spot`? Or actually, did you mean that the code in my `route/api/spots.js` file should be able to grab the right object?

Comment: Hm, not sure if this is part of the error, but when I tried this route in Postman: `localhost:5000/api/spots/5e4317871c9d440000b1613f`, all I got back was `null`

Comment: If null, it's mean this id `5e4317871c9d440000b1613f` is not found in your collection.

Comment: Ah I figured it out; strange, but all I had to do was restart all my servers :P

Comment: I can post another question if it's too different from this one, but after I have the `spot`'s `_id`, how can I get that object inside of my component? I'd like to render specific attributes from the object (i.e. `name`, `city`, etc.)

**NOTE:** I've tried using `Spot.findById()`, but I can't import `Spot` because the model file is outside of the `src` folder which holds all of my frontend actions, components, and reducers

Comment: Sure, maybe you can try with findOne, don't user findById. But, if you use `findOne`, the you've to pass the id. Example: `findOne({ _id: req.params.id });`

Comment: @TitusSutioFanpula Ah ok, so I'm looking at the documentation for the `findOne` method, and it looks like the syntax is something like this: `collection.findOne()`; in my case, what would the `collection` be?? I'm a bit confused as to how I'd use it in the `mapStateToProps` function.